# signal and child process

Tags: unix, ipc, signals

A quick and hopefully easy question.

I have a process A, which forks a process B. When I send a signal, e.g SIGINT, will both A and B receive it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
No.

From the moment fork was successful, those process will be independent from each other (except for wait() and stuff like that)